# How do I produce a time interval query in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an events based table that I would like to produce a query, by minute for the number of events that were occuring.

For example, I have an event table like:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
     session_id  TEXT,
     event       TEXT,
     time_stamp  DATETIME
)
```

Which I have transformed into the following type of table:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
     session_id    TEXT,
     start_ts      DATETIME,
     end_ts        DATETIME,
     duration      INTEGER
);
```

Now I want to create a query that would group the sessions by a count of those that were active during a particular minute.  Where I would essentially get back something like:

```
TIME_INTERVAL ACTIVE_SESSIONS
------------- ---------------
18:00         1
18:01         5
18:02         3
18:03         0
18:04         2
```

Comment: What's the meaning of "duration" if you already have "start_ts" and "end_ts"?

Comment: I could have left it out... it isn't germain to the question.  In my real world situation I do use an analog of this to avoid having to calculate the difference in the queries when doing queries on the duration.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to calculate exactly the intervals up to the next change? The rows would look like "18:00:32 | 18:04:17 | 1" and it would be much easier to compute. This "start|end|count" style of information would make it easier to draw charts, etc.

Comment: You have lost me I am afraid.  At the end of the day, I need to be able to graph over a period of time how many "sessions" are active in a given period of time (e.g. minutes).  While I appreciate the thoughts, I am afraid I am looking for the answer to the question I asked, sorry...

Comment: This is exactly what my proposed answer provides. What's wrong with that? I have _not_ implemented my additional "start|end|count" proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I got more what I wanted.  It doesn't account for intervals that are empty, but it is good enough for what I need.

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00.000',start_ts) TIME_INTERVAL, 
    (select count(session_id) 
      from sessions s2 
      where strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00.000',s1.start_ts) between s2.start_ts and s2.end_ts) ACTIVE_SESSIONS
   from sessions s1
   group by strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00.000',start_ts);
```

This will generate a row per minute for the period that the data covers with a count for the number of sessions that were had started (start_ts) but hadn't finished (end_ts).

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL allows the following query.

In contrast to your example, this returns an additional column for the day, and it omits the minutes where nothing happened (count=0).

```
select
    day, hour, minute, count(*)
from
    (values ( 0),( 1),( 2),( 3),( 4),( 5),( 6),( 7),( 8),( 9),
            (10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),
            (20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),
            (30),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(37),(38),(39),
            (40),(41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49),
            (50),(51),(52),(53),(54),(55),(56),(57),(58),(59))
     as minutes (minute),
    (values ( 0),( 1),( 2),( 3),( 4),( 5),( 6),( 7),( 8),( 9),
            (10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),
            (20),(21),(22),(23))
     as hours (hour),
    (select distinct cast(start_ts as date) from sessions
     union
     select distinct cast(end_ts as date) from sessions)
     as days (day),
    sessions
where
    (day,hour,minute)
    between (cast(start_ts as date),extract(hour from start_ts),extract(minute from start_ts))
        and (cast(end_ts as date),  extract(hour from end_ts),  extract(minute from end_ts))
group by
    day, hour, minute
order by
    day, hour, minute;
```

Comment: you could use the extension generate_series.
range(start,end,step) in place of "values(1),(2), ... ":
    `.load generate_series.dll`
    `SELECT hours.value, minute.value from generate_series(1,59,1) as minute;
    JOIN generate_series(1,24,1) as hours`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly your query, but I think it could help. Did you look into the SQLite [R-Tree module](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html)? This would allow you to create a virtual index on the start/stop time:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE sessions_index USING rtree (id, start, end);
```

Then you could search via:

```
SELECT * FROM sessions_index WHERE end >= <first minute> AND start <= <last minute>;
```